# The body of constexpr function not a return-statement

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constexpr, return-type

In the following program, I have added an explicit `return` statement in `func()`, but the compiler gives me the following error:

```
m.cpp: In function ‘constexpr int func(int)’:
m.cpp:11:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr int func(int)’ not a return-statement
 }
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int func (int x);

constexpr int func (int x) 
{
    if (x<0)                
        x = -x;
    return x; // An explicit return statement 
}

int main() 
{
    int ret = func(10);
    cout<<ret<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled program in a **g++** compiler using the following command.

```
g++ -std=c++11 m.cpp
```

I have added `return` statement in function, then **Why I got above error?**

Comment: You also don't need that declaration. A definition is also a declaration, and in this case, it harms readability IMO.

Comment: @tadman What? Of course `constexpr` function return values can depend on their arguments. What would be the point otherwise?

Comment: And the more interesting use would be: const int a=func(10); so computing a const-expression based on constexpr.

Comment: @Angew How much code can you cram into a `constexpr` before the compiler refuses to compile-time evaluate it?

Comment: @tadman In C++11, a single `return` statement. Since C++14, the sky (and [dcl.constexpr] and Annex B :-) ) is the limit. Similar to how template metaprogramming works.

Comment: @Angew Right you are. I was used to the C++11 behaviour where you couldn't really do much other than a `return` and the function was limited to being a sort of primitive macro.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++11's `constexpr` functions are more restrictive than that.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain only the following:
>
> - null statements (plain semicolons)
> - `static_assert` declarations
> - `typedef` declarations and alias declarations that do not define classes or enumerations
> - `using` declarations
> - `using` directives
> - exactly one `return` statement.

So you can say this instead:

```
constexpr int func (int x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x; }

static_assert(func(42) == 42, "");
static_assert(func(-42) == 42, "");

int main() {}
```

Note that this restriction was lifted in C++14.

Answer (score 27):

Prior to C++14, the body of a `constexpr` function must consist solely of a `return` statement: it cannot have any other statements inside it. This works in C++11 :

```
constexpr int func (int x) 
{
  return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}
```

In C++14 and up, what you wrote is legal, as are most other statements.

[Source.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)