# Why gcc5.4 doesn't compile a constexpr function calling a non-constexpr function, but icpc does?

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr, icc

gcc5.4 doesn't compile the following code:

```
// source.cpp
int nonconstexprfunc()
{
    return 14;
}

constexpr int func(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return nonconstexprfunc();
    return n*n;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int t1 = func(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The command I use:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -c source.cpp
```

The output:

```
In function ‘constexpr int func(int)’:
error: ‘constexpr int func(int)’ called in a constant expression
constexpr int t1 = func(0);
In function ‘int main()’:
error: ‘constexpr int func(int)’ called in a constant expression
constexpr int t1 = func(0);
```

But I can compile that source.cpp using gcc6.4. Doesn't gcc5.4 fully support constexpr functions?

More interestingly I can compile that source.cpp using icpc (Intel C++ compiler) that uses gcc5.4 - I suppose there must be an option to compile that code using gcc5.4.

```
$  icpc -v
icpc version 19.0 (gcc version 5.4.0 compatibility)
$  icpc -std=c++14 -c source.cpp
no errors
```

Comment: icpc doesn't use gcc 5.4, it uses its standard library (header + so/a), and that's it.

Comment: Seems to be reproducible on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZVN4a4COwD3z6Icu). But, you know, no compiler is perfect. GCC 5.4 *could* have had a bug.

Comment: With ICPC do you mean the [International Collegiate Programming Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Collegiate_Programming_Contest)? Then why did you add the `icc` tag for the Intel C/C++ Compiler? Please be careful when selecting tags, and edit as soon as you find a mistake.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude icpc is an Intel C++ compiler

Comment: Okay, so not the competition then. And in that case note that the version messages says "gcc version 5.4.0 ***compatibility***". It's *not* using GCC 5.4, it's only *compatible* with GCC 5.4 (though in this case not that compatible since it didn't implement the GCC bug). The Intel C/C++ Compiler is a totally separate compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first limitation is concerning the use gcc 5.4 with -std=c++11 which produces the error because of the two return statement see [The body of constexpr function not a return-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097171/the-body-of-constexpr-function-not-a-return-statement) so in order to lift your first issue you need to use -std=c++14

It then produces

> '#1 with x86-64 gcc 5.4
>   : In function 'constexpr int func(int)':
>
> :10:32: error: call to non-constexpr function 'int
>   nonconstexprfunc()'
>
> ```
>      return nonconstexprfunc();        ^
> ```
>
> : In function 'int main()':
>
> :16:28: error: 'constexpr int func(int)' called in a constant
>   expression
>
> ```
>  constexpr int t1 = func(0);
>
>                          Compiler returned: 1
> ```

This next error produced seems to be a known GCC bug (misinterpretation of c++14) see
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86678
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67026

You can also check out [calling non constexpr function from constexpr allowed in some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726503/calling-non-constexpr-function-from-constexpr-allowed-in-some-conditions)

However judging from the error it produces:

It seems pretty obvious that doing

```
constexpr int nonconstexprfunc()
{
    return 14;
}
```

will solve the error and will be more efficient in your case.
Check the difference with https://www.godbolt.org/ of adding constexpr or not using gcc 8.2 for example.

Comment: Thanks! But which version of gcc is being considered in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86678?

Comment: The latest 8.2 I believe.

Comment: No) I can compile that source.cpp using gcc6.4

Comment: Your example is a little bit different from http:\\gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86678? . If you try to compile the example constexpr bool always_true() { return true; }
int f() { return 1; }
constexpr int g() {
  if (always_true())
    return 0;
  return f();
} you will see that there still is a problem with gcc8.2 and gcc 6.4 for that matter. So I confirm that the gcc being considered is gcc8.2. And to avoid this problem try using constexpr until the gcc 9 release

Comment: Well, if it is a little different then maybe the reason of the error is different too?

Comment: I can not modify the source code that contains similar original code. But I'd like to know exactly the reason

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you can't modify the source code I believe your only option is to switch to gcc6.4 with -std=c++14. And beware of the limitation in gcc for the time being.